# Scala with Spray Routing - accessing GET parameters?

Tags: java, scala, spray

I'm currently working on an application built in Scala with Spray routing.

So for dealing with a JSON document sent over POST, it's pretty easy to access the variables within the body, as follows;

```
respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
    entity(as[String]) { body =>
        val msg = (parse(body) \ "msg").extract[String]
        val url = (parse(body) \ "url").extractOpt[String]
```

However, I'm now trying to write an additional query with GET, and am having some issues accessing the parameters sent through with the query.

So, I'm opening with;

```
get {
    respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
    parameterSeq { params =>
        var paramsList = params.toList
```

So, this works well enough in that I can access the GET params in a sequential order (just by accessing the index) - the problem is, unfortunately I don't think we can expect GET params to always be sent in the correct order.

The list itself prints out in the following format;

```
List((msg,this is a link to google), (url,http://google.com), (userid,13))
```

Is there any simple way to access these params? For example, something along the lines of;

```
var message = paramsList['msg']
println(message) //returns "this is a link to google"
```

Or am I going about this completely wrong?

Apologies if this is a stupid question - I've only switched over to Scala very recently, and am still getting both acquainted with that, and re-acquainted with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is use the [parameters directive](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.4/spray-routing/parameter-directives/parameters/) to parse the data out to a case class which contains all the relevant data:

```
case class MyParams(msg: String, url: String, userId: Int)

parameters(
  "msg".as[String],
  "url".as[String],
  "userId".as[Int]
).as[MyParams] {
  myParams => 
   // Here you have the case class containing all the data, already parsed.
}
```

Comment: Hey there! Many thanks, this appears to be on the right track - unfortunately though, I'm getting landed back with a compile-time error.

scala:173: too many arguments for method apply: (v1: Seq[(String, String)] => (spray.routing.RequestContext => Unit))spray.routing.RequestContext => Unit in trait Function1
[error]           parameterSeq("msg".as[String], "url".as[String], "userId".as[String]).as[searchParams] { params =>
[error]                       ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed

Comment: for reference, searchParams are defined as: case class searchParams(msg: String, url: String, userId: String)

Comment: Apologies for the spamposting - just switched ParamSeq over to simply parameters, but now it's throwing back a type mismatch on the params var itself. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the type mismatch?

Comment: Missing Parameter Type: searchParams

Comment: You dont need `parameterSeq`, you need `parameters`.

Comment: Yep, I switched to parameters.. case class SearchParams(msg: String, url: String, userId: String)
          parameters("msg".as[String], "url".as[String], "userId".as[String]).as[SearchParams] { searchParams => println(searchParams)

Comment: And you still get a type mismatch?

Comment: Yep, I'm afraid so. Pasted full code here, for readability: http://pastebin.com/ZLRsQ3Z9 . Also tried moving the case class outside of the def mainRoute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137453/discussion-between-yuval-itzchakov-and-eoghan).

Comment: Hey Yuval, opened the chat discussion - just waiting on you :)

Answer (score 1):

To build your routes you could use the [`parameters`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.4/spray-routing/parameter-directives/parameters/) directives. I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, anyway you could use them as:

```scala
get {
  parameters('msg) { (msg) =>
    complete(s"The message is '$msg'")
  }
}
```

Spray directives can be easily composed so you can use combine them in any way you want.

I hope that helps you.